# Why does "Host" header changing POST to GET request?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I've searched many articles, but none of them answered my question

I have a code in NestJS:

```
this.http.post(url, {
  // some params
}, {
  // here must be headers
  Host: 'www.webhook.site'
}
```

When the 'Host' header is set, my POST request switches to GET somehow
And webhook.site tells that it's getting GET request, not POST
And when I am removing 'Host' header, it's okay and works as expected (I mean POST request becoming POST request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to `www.webhook.site` receive a 301 redirect to `webhook.site`.

Clients following 301 redirects switch to GET requests.

Comment: omg
thank youuu so much!

Comment: is that mean, the url > host header? if my url says, for example, that I follow 'www.something.com' but my host says 'www.example.com', I will follow 'www.example.com' or I'll just get an error and that's all?

Comment: The URL consists of the scheme (which is used to determine if, for example, the request should use HTTP), the host (which is used to determine where to make the request to and generate the Host header) and the rest (which is set with the very (e.g. POST). You're overriding the Host header so the client isn't generating it from the URL.

Comment: sheesh, I didn't even expect that behavior
thank you!